# remove client table spacing between rows

Tags: html, asp.net

I have the following table:

For some reason, When I render this there is an enormous space between each row! I have searched everywhere and I just don't know how to eliminate the space. I tried manually setting the height of each row but that still did not prove useful, the default huge space overrides everything i throw at it. Any suggestions?

```
<table style="display:block;">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1"><p>תעודת זהות</p></td>
                <td><telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" id="txtId" Skin="Metro"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1"><p>סיסמא</p></td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Skin="Metro" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1"><p>שם פרטי</p></td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtfName" runat="server" Skin="Metro" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1"><p>שם משפחה</p></td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtlName" runat="server" Skin="Metro" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1"><p>מספר טלפון</p></td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtmPhone" runat="server" Skin="Metro" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1"><p>כתובת</p></td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Skin="Metro" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1"><p>אימייל</p></td>
                <td>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Skin="Metro" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

style:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 126px;
    }

    table tr td p {
        font-family: Arial;
    }
</style>
```

NOTE: In the design view of visual studio there is no spacing, it looks fine. only when rendering it comes out this way.

Comment: I just added to the code my style segment. @Moshtaf

Comment: Try `<style> tr, td, p { margin : 0px; padding : 0px; } </style>` and then tell me what happens???

Comment: @MaryMelody Thank you, this works great. I never thought the default p element padding was causing this issue. This works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<style type="text/css">

tr, td, p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

</style>`
```

Answer (score 0):

A table always has a padding. So add to your CSS padding: 0;

```
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
     width: 126px;
 }

table tr td p {
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 0;

}
</style>
```